# Launching a new activity inside a different tab

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the following code to launch an activity in a new tab from an ActivityGroup inside a tab:

```
    TabHost mTabHost = TabsFragment.getTabHost();    
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    Intent i = new Intent(Downloader.this,Test.class);
    replaceContentView(Test.class.getName(),i);
    public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
this.setContentView(view);}
```

With this code, I am able to switch to a new tab, but the problem I have is, before calling the oncreate() of Test activity, the current ActivityGroup's oncreate() is being called. After that though the oncreate() of Test.class is called(confirmed through logs), Downloader activity is being continued to display in the new tab, instead of the Test activity.

Why this happens, though I could not find any reasons for the afore mentioned?

Any help in resolving the same is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depend on your activity stack if your current exactly on top of the parent activity you can just finish current actvity and it will go to previous activity. If you want to clear all activity stack and start over new activity try

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, activity.class);
             intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
            startActivity(intent1);
```

Comment: I tried two options (1) Added the two flags to intent and used replaceContentView as shown in my post. The result was the same (2) Added the two flags and startActivity as suggested in your answer. It started a new activity instead of showing the activity inside the current tab